# trigger to generate account no .on insert into a table

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

im a beginner in java servlet my problem is i want to generate a account no . eachtime there would be a new account on my table.but the trigger is not workin pls help the othe values like fname lname username and pword etc are workin fine the servlet is ok but the trigger for creating the accno is not workin properly

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER T1 BEFORE INSERT ON UINFO
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
set new.UACCNO="jith"||to_char(SQ_1.nextval,'FM0009');
END;
/
```

//`this is my servlet prog`

```
String s1=hreq.getParameter("fname");
            String s2=hreq.getParameter("lname");
            String s3=hreq.getParameter("uacc");
            String s4=hreq.getParameter("uname");
            String s5=hreq.getParameter("pword");
            String s6=hreq.getParameter("pword2");
            String s7[]=hreq.getParameterValues("select");
            String s8=hreq.getParameter("uans");
            String s9=hreq.getParameter("ueid");
            PrintWriter pw=hres.getWriter();

    //if passwords match        

        if(s6.equals(s5))
        {

            PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement("insert into uinfo(fname,lname,uacc,uname,pword,uques,uans,ueid) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
pstmt.setString(1,s1);
pstmt.setString(2,s2);
pstmt.setString(3,s3);
pstmt.setString(4,s4);
pstmt.setString(5,s5);
for(int i=0;i<s7.length;i++)
{
if(s7[i]!=null)
pstmt.setString(6,s7[i]);

}
pstmt.setString(7,s8);
pstmt.setString(8,s9);
pstmt.executeUpdate();
pw.println("<html><body  bgcolor=wheat text=blue>");
pw.println("<h1>user  "+s4+"  has Registered successfully</h1><br/><br/>");
pw.println("<h3><a href=login.html>Login Now?</a></h3>");
 pw.println("</body></html>");
 }
 else
 {
            pw.println("<html><body  bgcolor=wheat text=blue>");
            pw.println("<h1>**the passwords do not match go back and check</h1>");
            pw.println("</body></html>");
    }
```

Comment: the servlet is ok it shows mw that user is registered if pawwsords match pls help

Comment: what do you mean by *"the trigger for creating the accno is not workin properly"*? And please format and correctly indent your code

Comment: Have you tried inserting records from the SQL prompt, and does the trigger fire then? I'd suggest getting that part working before worrying about the webapp part of it.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? If this is Oracle then it should be "new:UACCNO", the period is incorrect.

Comment: im using oracle but im not able to under stand how to append the string to if i new.UACCNO=to_char(SQ_1.nextval,'FM0009') then im gettin 0001 0002 i want a string like jith00001 jith00002

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Trigger to create a consecutive for a record is overkill, you should call the sequence from another PreparedStatement, like this:

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement( "SQ_1.nextval from dual")
```

Then after pulling out the consecutive, do the required transformation to create your key and pass it in the insert statement.

Another option you have is directly passing the `SQ_1.nextval` in the insert statement, but this might depend on the db engine you are using.

If it's oracle as I suspect, It would be like this (please note the example below is not doing the concatenation/transforming you do in the trigger, I leave that up to you):

```
PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(
"insert into uinfo(UACCNO,fname,lname,uacc,uname,pword,uques,uans,ueid) values(SQ_1.nextval,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: Agree that if in Oracle that using the sequence is the idiomatic way to do it.